# How to send data from first tab to second tab in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have two tab first and second. I want to send data from first tab to second tab on swapping...please help me to solve this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: your question is incomplete. There is not enough information to identify exact context. please read question writing guide.

Answer (score 1):

**There is no method that passes data to one tab to another tab.**

You can use any of the common class to save you data from the tab and then when you go to the another tab you can read this in call of onCreateActivity() or onCreateView().

**for example if you want to save any string data**

```
public class YourApplication extends Application {
    public String data="";
    private static YourApplication mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mInstance = this;

    }

    @Override
    public void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        MultiDex.install(base);
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
    }


    public static synchronized YourApplication getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }
    public void setData(String data){
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
```

in this class you can store any kind of data.

Use it like this

```
YourApplication.getInstance().setData("data");

YourApplication.getInstance().getData();
```

Comment: well, thanks u sir,it works for me, but while using data send from first tab in second tab to get data from database as  query parameter,application crashes

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

**Tab1**

```
Intent i = getParent().getIntent();
i.putExtra("a", a);
i.putExtra("b", b);
i.putExtra("tab", 1);
TabActivity ta = (TabActivity) Tab1.this.getParent();
ta.getTabHost().setCurrentTab(1);
```

**Tab2**

```
Intent i = getParent().getIntent();
int a = i.getIntExtra("a", 0);
int b = i.getIntExtra("b", 0);
```